# Wallet.dat bitcoin cash?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet, bitcoin-cash, wallet.dat

I had 20 btc in 2012, and I spent it all in December 2017. I heard there was a fork for Bitcoin cash.

How do I get my 20 bitcoin cash out of my wallet.dat ?

Comment: Run Bitcoin Core. Use `dumpwallet` to save private keys. Download a Bitcoin Cash wallet from https://electroncash.org/ Once you set it up go Wallet > Private Keys > Sweep. Good luck, this should be straightforward.